# Tables Summary into single table in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have two tables named '`Customers`' and '`Committeetables`' in mysql database. They have following columns
Table: Customer

```
nd       Name     FatherName      Cell#   AdvanceAmount
25       Waseem     Asghar        0302        2500
30       Ramzan     Khan          0303        3500
35       Rana       Ali           0307        2000
```

Table: CommitteeTables

```
nd       Amount            RecievingDate        DrawDate
25        1500               2-10-15             10-10-15
30        1500               2-10-15             10-10-15
25        1500               3-10-15             10-11-15
30        1500               3-10-15             10-11-15
35        1500               3-10-15             10-11-15
```

A Column '`nd`' in '`Customers`' table is primary key and in '`CommitteeTables`' table is foreign key. It means '`Customers`' table joins with '`ComitteeTables`' table through '`nd`' column.
Expected Result table should be as under:

```
nd     Name     Father Name     Cell#       Advance       Amount     Balance
25     Waseem     Asghar        0302        25000           3000     22000
30     Ramzan     Khan          0303        35000           3000     32000
32     Rana       Ali           0307        20000           1500     18500
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                total      80000           7500      72500
```

I am using Laravel 5 and HTML, Bootstrap. I need this result in Laravel 5. I shall be really thankful if someone help me to solve  my problem.

Thanks

Waseem

Comment: Have you tried any queries so far?

Answer (score 0):

This is not at all a Laravel question. It's a general SQL question.

Something like this:

```
SELECT nd, Name, FatherName, Cell#, AdvanceAmount as Advance,
    (SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM CommitteeTables WHERE CommitteeTables.nd=Custoemr.nd) as Amount, Advance-Balance AS Balance
FROM Customer;
```

I'm not entirely sure that's correct but you can try it and fix any errors.  As Bogdan suggests you should try something first then come back here with any problems that you have.

Comment: I need out put table in View in Laravel.